# How do I write loops inside functions?

Tags: javascript

The question is to write a for loop inside a function that will take in array and return the total of all the numbers added together. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
let total = 0

function totalGoals(numbers) {
  for (let i = 0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
    let num = numbers[i]
    total = total + num
  }
  return total
}
totalGoals([0, 1, 2])
```

Comment: that is correct

Comment: I thought it was, however the program I wrote it in is returning 6 and telling me my code is incorrect.

Comment: the portion u mention is correct.. can you share the part which is using it

Comment: Why is total outside the function?

Comment: The code you’ve given here will return 3, not 6. Each subsequent call of “totalGoals” will add to the previous due to “total” not being inside the function.

Comment: Where should the total be defined?

Comment: I have no idea why but it's returning 6

Comment: I would expect total be defined inside the function. Would you agree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define `total` variable globally (outside of function), so here are 2 options: it's better to define variable for sum inside the function:

```
function totalGoals(numbers) {
  let total = 0
  for (let i = 0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
    let num = numbers[i]
    total = total + num
  }
  return total
}
totalGoals([0, 1, 2])
```

or if it is necessary to be global - set it to 0 in the start of function, so if won't be affected if function is called more than once:

```
let total = 0    
function totalGoals(numbers) {
  total = 0
  for (let i = 0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
    let num = numbers[i]
    total = total + num
  }
  return total
}
totalGoals([0, 1, 2])
```

Answer (score 2):

First, lets confirm that you HAVE to learn the basics of Javascript and basic looping (using for loop for example), but also on your journey, you have to learn what tools in the language might make your life easier and your code mode readable.

When it comes to accumulative operation (like adding and so..) you should learn about "reduce" method, which you can write your desired function like:

```
function totalGoals(numbers){
  return numbers.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some sytanxys problems. Try this code:

```
function totalGoals(numbers) {

        let total= 0, num = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i< numbers.length; i++) {
            num = numbers[i];
            total = total + num;
        }

        alert(total);

    return total;
    }
    totalGoals([0, 1, 2]);
```

You need to learn about **Scope of variable:**
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

And you need be more **carefully** with your **sintaxys**:
Dont forget add `;` at final of a code line.
And also you are start the variable `num` more than one time with the word `let` inside your loop.